# Using Bitcoin ATM's, how does selling work?

Tags: wallet, sell-bitcoins, bitcoin-atm

How do Bitcoin ATM's work? I have a wallet on my computer and wanted to know how would the bitcoins there be transferred to the ATM and exchanged for cash.

Could somebody explain this process to me?

Answer (score 1):

1. Atm will generate a bitcoin deposit address
2. Client scan it using smartphone and send bitcoin to that address
3. Atm will wait for confirmation and emit fiat money from dispenser

Things to consider:
KYC level for bitcoin amounts 
Generation of addresses 
Confirmation number
ATM connected full node 
Rate exchange 
And more , but I believe this is the basic.

Answer (score 0):

There are various types of Bitcoin ATM's, only some of them offer to *sell* Bitcoin. Here is a list of some of those types and a good explanation of the selling process:

https://coinatmradar.com/blog/how-to-sell-bitcoins-using-bitcoin-atm/

Typically you receive a voucher and an address to send the Bitcoins to, then redeem the cash using the voucher, after the transaction has confirmed.

Answer (score -2):

Following are the steps are followed for the usage of the bitcoin ATM machine :

1. Open the QR code for your Bitcoin wallet on a smartphone. You can get a bitcoin wallet from Coinbase if you don’t already have 
       one! Don’t forget to download Coinbase’s app for iPhone or Android from the AppStore or GooglePlay.
2. Then run the QR code under the bitcoin ATM machine’s scanner.
3. Enters the amount of cash to be exchanged for Bitcoins.
4. Waits for the machine to process the transaction and give out a confirmation.
5. Check your bitcoin wallet to see if the Bitcoins transaction is processed

Comment: This is a good answer, however, the OP is asking about selling his Bitcoin's, not buying them.